# RelativeLayout with wrap_content and aligning to layout_center* issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Problem appears when we set `RelativeLayout` size (width or height) to `wrap_conent` and then try to align child view to another **centered** child view.

On below example we have 3 RLs:

- cyan and yellow RLs has `layout_height="wrap_content"`
- magenta RL with has `layout_height="100dp"`

where everyone has:

- red square centered vertically (`layout_centerVertical="true"`)
- green square that we try to `alignBottom` to red square (`android:layout_alignBottom="@id/red"`)
- text with various length that resize our RL

[image: RelativeLayoutIssue]

As you can see first row has wrong positioned green square.

Similar situation is with horizontal dimens and positioning.

I know that `RelativeLayout` has some restrictions when we set one of it size to `wrap_content` but I always think that it applies only to position directly to parent:

> Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. For example, you cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM.

I know, that they're many hacks with nested containers but when we create a layout for list item then it should be as flat as possible.

Did I missed something?

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0ff">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/red1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#f00"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/red1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/red1"
            android:background="#0f0"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/red1"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta."/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#f0f">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/red2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#f00"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/red2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/red2"
            android:background="#0f0"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/red2"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta."/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/red3"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#f00"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/red3"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/red3"
            android:background="#0f0"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/red3"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim."/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Interesting, it is happening because text of textview in your first relative layout is big. When i reduce that text size, it is coming normally. i don't think it is a development issue

Comment: keep android:layout_alignParentTop="true" in View 'red1', and give some top margin if it is ok even it is not in center.

Comment: @Srikanth You see - I'm a pixel perfect man so it's important to have a layout_centerVertical="true" parameter

Comment: yes, thats why i mentioned 'if it is ok even it is not in center'